# CSS Grid not using 100% of the width of the screen

Tags: css, css-grid

Take the example snippet below:

```css
.grid-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
}

.grid-item {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
    <div class="grid-item">item 1</div>
    <div class="grid-item">item 2</div>
    <div class="grid-item">item 3</div>
</div>
```

The result is a table [that looks like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xjVNZ.png) My problem is that I want to eliminate the 10 pixel gaps to the left, right and the top of the table, so that it covers 100% of the width (basically, I want it to start at 0, 0). The only thing that I've found that works is setting the margin to `margin: -10px -10px 0 -10px;` in `.grid-container` however that seems like the wrong way of going about it.

Am I missing something painfully obvious here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just need to remove the default padding and margin from the body. Browsers add their own default `CSS`. That is why you are seeing that padding:

**Like this:-**

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.grid-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
}

.grid-item {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
    <div class="grid-container">
        <div class="grid-item">item 1</div>
        <div class="grid-item">item 2</div>
        <div class="grid-item">item 3</div>
    </div>
```

Check also Eric Meyer's CSS reset to remove all browser default CSS.

[Eric Meyer's CSS reset](https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```css
html, body {margin:0; padding:0}

.grid-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
}

.grid-item {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
    <div class="grid-item">item 1</div>
    <div class="grid-item">item 2</div>
    <div class="grid-item">item 3</div>
</div>
```